# Missing Plugins in QGIS 2.6

Tags: qgis, plugins

Do I need to re-install plugins after upgrading to 2.6?
Not all the plugins I had on QGIS 2.4 appear on 2.6.

Answer (score 2):

All QGIS 2.x plugins should run with QGIS 2.6 too. It might be that some plugins need an update.

You can look under "installed" plugins if the missing plugins are present, but unchecked.

Comment: Thanks, I checked it and wtill some plugins are missing (found them under "uninstalled"). Could there be an error in the installation of the QGIS on my computer?

Comment: Which operating system are you working on?

Comment: Windows 7 professional

Comment: The python plugins should reside in `C:\users\<name>\.qgis2\python\plugins`. The update to QGIS 2.6 shoud not delete them. If you have got the icons on the desktop, the installation was successful.